# Cancel a bake that freezes UI with black box percentage counter

Tags: interface

Sometimes, when you bake, you see a small black box that counts up to 100 showing the progress of the bake.  For example, while baking a cloth simulation.

[image]

Is it possible to cancel the bake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key on the keyboard to cancel the bake.

Some bakes have a progress bar in the 'Info' header, these can be cancelled by pressing the small **X** next to the progress bar or by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.